# Reordering the linq statement after group by

Tags: linq

Basicly, i have a statement which is like that

```
Contents
.Where(x=>x.CategoryId==5 && x.Status==1)
.GroupBy(q=>q.VersionId)
.OrderByDescending(q=>q.Key)
.Take(100)  
.Select(q => new { VersionId = q.Key, MajorVersion = q.Max(x => x.MajorVersion) })
```

At the moment, it looks like below. But i want to reorder MajorVersion field as a descending...

```
VersionId     MajorVersion
387276        2
365015        1
355427        3
369865        1
```

How do i do that?

Answer (score 2):

Select returns an `IEnumerable` so you can do further sorting/ordering etc after.

```
Contents
.Where(x => x.CategoryId == 5 && x.Status == 1)
.GroupBy(q => q.VersionId)
.OrderByDescending(q => q.Key)
.Take(100)  
.Select(q => new { VersionId = q.Key, MajorVersion = q.Max(x => x.MajorVersion) })
.OrderByDescending(x => x.MajorVersion);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just move the `OrderByDescending` after the `Select`.
You will then be able to sort by the fields in the select.  (since you'll be calling `OrderByDescending` on the IQueryable of anonymous types returned by `Select()`)

Comment: `OrderByDescending` cannot be **moved** after the `Select`. It must be **added** because of the call to `Take(100)`.